# Не работает npm-migrate

Tags: node.js, npm

Мне нужно из одного артифактори( на jfrog )перелить артифакты в другой( на Nexus) для этого использую https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-migrate

```
const migrate = require('npm-migrate')
 
const moduleName = 'my-private-module'
const from = 'http://your-old.private-registry.com:8080'
const to = 'http://nice-new.private-registry.org:8080'
 
// optional
const options = {
    debug: false // default
}
 
migrate(moduleName, from, to, options)
    .then((migrated) => console.log(migrated)) // list of migrated packages
    .catch((err) => console.error(err))
```

в from и tu указываю адреса, но консоль выдает ошибку

```
ParserError:
Line |
  12 |  migrate(moduleName, from, to, options)
     |                    ~
     | Missing argument in parameter list.
```

Что не так я сделал?

Comment: Я вам вчера на хабре прокомментировал. Вы запускаете скрипт не нодой, а повершеллом

Comment: о, не увидел комментария, спасибо

Comment: Сначала выполнял в PowerShell, и получал ошибку выше, затем начал выполнять в окне Node.js командой `.load и путь к файлу.json` после этого он отображает содержание файла, но выдает ошибку  `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'npm-migrate'
Require stack:
- <repl>
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '<repl>' ]`